# Unable to import a jsx module in my react-application with webpack 4 and babel 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

After going through almost all the answers related to this topic I had no luck so have to create a new question.

Problem Statement :

I have a library (module) that I want to import inside my react application which has an export syntax like(working in another app) :

```
export * from './button'; // this returns jsx component
```

Now, in my application I am using this as :

```
import {button} from ./library; // this is the bundled module where button component exists.
```

When I do this **Webpack** gives me an error :

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export * from './button';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

As written, I am using Webpack 4 and babel 7 with these configurations :

**webpack.config.js**

//this is exports.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        client: ['whatwg-fetch', './client/index.js', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client']
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist/client/${pkg.version}`),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: `/myApp/${pkg.version}`
    },
    devtool: ifProduction('nosources-source-map', 'source-map'),
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve('./client'), path.resolve('./node_modules')]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff|woff2?)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|svg|eot|ttf)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    mode,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            openAnalyzer: false,
            reportFilename: '../report.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

**babel.config.js**

```
//  prettier-ignore
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-spread',
        'react-hot-loader/babel',
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
                regenerator: true,
            },
        ],
    ],
    env: {
        development: {
            presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env', ['@babel/preset-react', { development: true } ],
            ],
        },
        test: {
            presets: [['@babel/preset-env'], '@babel/preset-react'],
        },
    },
};
```

I am not sure what's going wrong, Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a valid syntax.

```
export * from './button';
```

You need to list what you export.

```
export {button}
```

or

```
export default button
```

Comment: Okay, I dun think that it is even going till there, Problem is it is telling that export is an invalid syntax over there.